# Typescript Date object to Json difference

Tags: json, typescript, date, utc, stringify

I have the following object

```
export interface IExample {
    Name?: string; 
    SomeId: number; 
    DateReceived?: Date; 
}
```

When I map my mat-datepicker value to DateReceived I get this:

```
Wed Oct 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

...all good, then I stringify it and I get this:

```
2018-10-23T23:00:00.000Z
```

I understand whats going on - since I am in the UK I'm an hour behind UTC which is the standard reflected in the stringified object - the hour difference.

That's all good and I could fix it adding an hour to my DateReceived property before stringifying it, and it will be safe because my app will never be used outside GMT timezone.

Is there a more elegant solution though?

Comment: When you'll parse the JSON back - you'll get exactly same date. Why do you think you should to do anything?

Comment: Because the string is sent to WebAPI that expects this: 
Post([FromBody] JObject request)
and when I deserialize it the following way:
var deserialisedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(request)
I still get those properties reflecting the hour deifference.